# Unable to find macros undefined in C++ standard library header files

Tags: c++, c, macros, std

I know that for every **<header.h>** in the C standard library, C++ has a **<cheader>** header file, e.g. **<stdio.h>** and **<cstdio>**.

Every **<cheader>** will include its corresponding **<header.h>** and undefine a large list of macros which correspond to standard library functions, such as:

```
/*sample taken from cstdlib*/
// Get rid of those macros defined in <stdlib.h> in lieu of real functions.
#undef abort
#undef abs
#undef atexit
/* ... */
```

and pass the respective functions into the std namespace:

```
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
  _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

  using ::div_t;
  using ::ldiv_t;

  using ::abort;
  using ::abs;
  using ::atexit;
  /* ... */
}
```

Looking at stdlib.h there is no trace of these macros, only the normal function prototypes. Doing a recursive search with grep at **/usr/include** showed me that they are not defined, only undefined at the **<cheader>** files. What am I missing?

My gcc version is 5.4.0, and I am in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS which comes bundled with Windows 10

Comment: They don't have to be macros (those you mention will normally not be), but they might be. This is belt-and-braces programming in your specific implementation, and is not required by the C++ Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that all you describe is specific to the particular library implementation you are observing and not common to all C or C++ libraries for all compilers.

Undefining a macro that is not defined has no effect.  In order to be independent from the C library used, the C++ headers may undefine all standard symbols *in case* not *because* they are defined as macros.

For example in a free-standing environment (no OS), it is not possible to use the standard GNU C as it has operating system and POSIX dependencies.  In this case an alternative C library such as Newlib may be used.  However the GNU C++ library only has dependencies on the standard C library, so can be used with an alternative C library where they may be defined as macros.

Comment: Ah I think I got it. So the C++ implementation I have is decoupled from the C implementation I also have. Those undefines are a precaution against the case that a C library used as a dependency had those standard functions defined as macros, which is already rare.